# Passing state, onEvent to TabItem func (Kotlin, Jetpack Compose)

Tags: kotlin, tabs, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I'm trying to make mobile app, where will be 2 tabs: registration and login, user can sign up and data store in room. I created tabs, userState, userViewModel and etc, but I cant understand how to pass state and onEvent parameters (for creating user) to RegistrationScreen(), because it's TabItem.

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val db by lazy {
        Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext,
            UserDatabase::class.java,
            "users.db"
        ).allowMainThreadQueries().build()
    }
    private val viewModel by viewModels<UserViewModel>(
        factoryProducer = {
            object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
                override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                    return UserViewModel(db.dao) as T
                }
            }
        }
    )

    @ExperimentalPagerApi
    @ExperimentalMaterialApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

            val state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()
//            UserScreen(state = state, onEvent = viewModel::onEvent)
            MainScreen(state = state, onEvent = viewModel::onEvent)
        }
    }
```

TabItem.kt

```
typealias ComposableFun = @Composable () -> Unit

sealed class TabItem(var icon: Int, var title: String, var screen: ComposableFun) {
    object Regisration : TabItem(R.drawable.ic_music, "Registration", { RegistrationScreen() })
    object Login : TabItem(R.drawable.ic_movie, "Login", { LoginScreen() })
}
```

ContentScreen.kt

```
@Composable
fun RegistrationScreen(
//    state: UserState,
//    onEvent: (UserEvent) -> Unit,
) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.TopStart)
                .padding(20.dp, top = 40.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {

            val phone = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            val username = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
            val password = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
            val confirmPassword = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
            TextField(
                label = { Text(text = "Phone number") },
                value = phone.value,
                onValueChange = { phone.value = it },
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Phone))


            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
            TextField(
                label = { Text(text = "Username") },
                value = username.value,
                onValueChange = { username.value = it })

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
            TextField(
                label = { Text(text = "Password") },
                value = password.value,
                visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation(),
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password),
                onValueChange = { password.value = it })

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
            TextField(
                label = { Text(text = "Confirm Password") },
                value = confirmPassword.value,
                visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation(),
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password),
                onValueChange = { confirmPassword.value = it })

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
            Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(40.dp, 0.dp, 40.dp, 0.dp)) {
                var openDialog = remember {
                    mutableStateOf(false)
                }
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        if (password.value != confirmPassword.value) {
                            openDialog.value = true
                        } else {


//                            state.name = username.value.toString()
//                            UserEvent.SetName(name = username.value.toString())
//                            UserEvent.SetPassword(password = password.value.toString())
//                            UserEvent.SetPhoneNumber(phoneNumber = phone.value)
//                            UserEvent.SaveUser
//                            onEvent(UserEvent.SaveUser)
                        }
                    },
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(50.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(50.dp)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Continue")
                }
                if (openDialog.value) {
                    AlertDialog(
                        onDismissRequest = {
                            openDialog.value = false
                        },
                        title = { Text(text = "Error") },
                        text = { Text("Password mismatch") },
                        buttons = {
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

UserViewModel.kt

```
class UserViewModel(
    private val dao: UserDao
): ViewModel() {
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(UserState())
    private val _users =
        dao.getUsers().stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), emptyList())
    val state = combine(_state, _users) {state, users ->
        state.copy(
            users = users
        )
    }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), UserState())

    fun onEvent(event: UserEvent) {
        when(event) {
            is UserEvent.DeleteUser -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    dao.deleteUser(event.user)
                }
            }
            UserEvent.HideDialog -> {
                _state.update { it.copy(
                    isAddingUser = false
                ) }
            }
            UserEvent.SaveUser -> {
                val name = state.value.name
                val password = state.value.password
                val phoneNumber = state.value.phoneNumber
                if (name.isBlank() || password.isBlank() || phoneNumber.isBlank()) {
                    return
                }
                val user = User(
                    name = name,
                    password = password,
                    phoneNumber = phoneNumber
                )
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    dao.upsertUser(user)
                }
                _state.update { it.copy(
                    isAddingUser = false,
                    name = "",
                    password = "",
                    phoneNumber = "",
                ) }
            }
            is UserEvent.SetName -> {
                _state.update { it.copy(
                    name = event.name
                ) }
            }
            is UserEvent.SetPassword ->
                _state.update { it.copy(
                    password = event.password
                ) }
            is UserEvent.SetPhoneNumber -> {
                _state.update { it.copy(
                    phoneNumber = event.phoneNumber
                ) }
            }
            UserEvent.ShowDialog -> {
                _state.update { it.copy(
                    isAddingUser = true
                ) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried make state and onEvent global variables to use it in RegistrationScreen or pass it as arguments to this func, but I didn't understand how do it right.

Comment: Hi! I'm facing exactly the same problem: how to pass variables to composables that are used in sealed class. Did you find any workaround? Thank you!